# Generating a Quote PDF after record is locked

Tags: apex, pdf, quote

In our company, the sale rep. has to go through the approval process and then, when the record is locked, generate a PDF. The problem is that he cannot save the pdf in the quote since the record is locked (and it is locking `QuoteDocument` too).

Can we do something like `runAs()` outside an Apex test class (it seems to be possible when executed as sysadmin)?

**EDIT:**

I found this message in Salesforce's forums ([Locked Quote Allow Create PDF?](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Locked-Quote-Allow-Create-PDF/td-p/625847)) and their solution is basically to leave the record unlocked and to "emulate" a locked record with validation rules.

I highly prefer to lock the record (for security), but if there's no other option, I guess I won't have a choice but to go with this dirty workaround.

Comment: `System.runAs` is for test methods, as stated in the documentation. I don't have a definitive answer for what you *can* do though, but if I come across it, I'll post it here.

Comment: @sfdcfox This is what I noticed too, I use it at times in text classes, but it is not available in regular Apex classes.

Comment: What about a trigger - once the record is locked, the trigger will call your class that generates the PDF. The triggers don't run in the user's context so you should be able to override the lock...